# Doesn't show me the correct output

Tags: c#, loops, max, long-integer, min

The program i was compiling doesn't show me the correct output

the code is

```
using System;

namespace minsum
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(arr_temp,Int32.Parse);
            int i=0;
            long[] cal = new long[5];
            long max = 0;
            long min = 0;
            while(i < arr.Length)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    cal[i] += arr [j];
                }
                cal [i] = cal [i] - arr [i];
                i++;
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < arr.Length; l++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine (cal [l]);
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < arr.Length; k++) 
            {
                max = cal [0];
                min = cal [0];
                if (cal[k] > max) 
                {
                    max = cal [k];
                }
                else if (cal [k] < min) 
                {
                    min = cal [k];
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine ("finalmax: "+ max);
            Console.WriteLine ("finalmin: "+ min);
        }
    }
}
```

the input i gave to the program is 396285104 573261094 759641832 819230764 364801279
and the correct output will be max: 2548418794 and min: 2093989309
but it shows me a wrong min: 2516934969[image]

Comment: Why not use Math.Max and Math.Min? Also how can we help when we don't know what the calculation is for?

Comment: @john i some how found the answer and thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

In your third loop, you are resetting the values of min and max on every iteration. Move those two lines directly above your third loop and your problem will be solved.

```
// Initialize max and min here instead of in your loop
max = cal [0];
min = cal [0];

for (int k = 0; k < arr.Length; k++) 
{
    if (cal[k] > max) 
    {
        max = cal [k];
    }
    else if (cal [k] < min) 
    {
        min = cal [k];
    }

}
```